# How to forward X over SSH to configure a desktop manager within cubic remotely

Tags: networking, ssh, xorg, desktop-environments

I want to configure menus,windows,decorations,taskbars positions of the wanted desktop manager in real time inside cubic because I find it very comfortable to do that while I'm inside the cubic virtual environment. Below you can see that I tried to enable the X forwarding through ssh because I wanted to configure a desktop manager like lxde or xfce from within cubic,but it failed. Do you have a workaround ?

within cubic :

```
root@cubic:~# /etc/init.d/ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                                  sshd: no hostkeys available -- exiting.
[fail]

root@cubic:~# ssh-keygen -A
ssh-keygen: generating new host keys: RSA DSA ECDSA ED25519 

root@cubic:~# /etc/init.d/ssh start
 * Starting OpenBSD Secure Shell server sshd                                           [ OK ] 

root@cubic:~# adduser test

Adding user `test' ...
Adding new group `test' (1000) ...
Adding new user `test' (1000) with group `test' ...
Creating home directory `/home/test' ...
Copying files from `/etc/skel' ...
New password: 
Retype new password: 
passwd: password updated successfully
Changing the user information for test
Enter the new value, or press ENTER for the default
 Full Name []: 
 Room Number []: 
 Work Phone []: 
 Home Phone []: 
 Other []: 
Is the information correct? [Y/n] y
```

on the host os :

```
ziomario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:~$ ssh -Y test@192.168.1.4 (host os IP Number)

The authenticity of host '192.168.1.4 (192.168.1.4)' can't be established.
This key is not known by any other names
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? yes
Warning: Permanently added '192.168.1.4' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
test@192.168.1.4's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

it fails because the user test is not on the host os but on the cubic os,but 192.168.1.4 is the IP number of the host os (cubic has none). If I do : **ssh -Y test@192.168.1.4** inside cubic it will fails again because the user test is inside cubic,but the IP number is on the host os. If I create the user test on the host os and I will try to forward X using the host IP number and the user test,I will be able to configure xfce4 installed on the host os and that's not what I want.

Comment: Use the cubic vm's IP instead of host's.  I'm pretty sure it got one -- in cubic type ifconfig and see.

Comment: there isn't. It doesn't assign any IP number.

Comment: Setting up networking comes before setting up ssh.

Comment: can you give me some documentation to study ? thanks.

Comment: Try https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/network-configuration

Comment: do you realize that every change I made to the network configuration,it will be made to the host os and not inside the cubic virtual environment ?

Comment: I probably misunderstand your "cubic virtual environment:" to be a virtual machine.

Comment: did you already use cubic ? the terminal window is called virtual environment,but it's not a virtual machine. it seems to be a chroot cage.